# need to get value and add it into db

Tags: scala, lift

Hi I have the following code, and have the form.scala in my model folder but it runs in to an error message which reads,

```
 [error]  def getSingleton = SimpleForm
 [error]                     ^
 [error] three errors found
```

————————————————————
The code is as following:

```
   <lift:surround with="default" at="content">
    <div class="lift:SimpleForm?form=post">
      <input class="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="press me"/>
    </div>
   </lift:surround>
```

in snippets folder.

```
import net.liftweb._
import util._
import Helpers._
import http._

class SimpleForm extends StatefulSnippet {
 var name = ""
  override def dispatch = {case "render" => render}
  def render=
   "name=name" #> SHtml.text(name, name = _) &
    "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(myfunc)

  private def myfunc() = { var name = ""}


}
```

in model folder.

```
import net.liftweb._
import util._
import Helpers._
import http._

class SimpleForm extends LongKeyedMapper[SimpleForm] with IdPK {
def getSingleton = SimpleForm
}
```

It is supposed to get a name and add it to database I could solve the previous problem but do not know how to continue it.

Comment: And can you give us the contents of form.scala, contents of Boot.scala and path to those files?

Comment: @Rogach, thanks for your response, I could solve that issue but running into the above error.

Comment: Are you sure that those classes are in proper packages? Since I don't see package declarations in your code.

Comment: actually the class not found error is solved I need to find a way to get the value of name from form.

Comment: Look at your `myfunc()` - it should be called when submit button is pressed, and when it is called, `name` var should be equal to the value that was typed in actual form field. And instead of getting that value, for some reason you discard it: `var name = ""`.

Comment: Also I believe that input should have "name" attribute set to "name", not class: `<input name="name" ><input>`.